# Code to calculate the difference in months between 2 date variables

Tags: date, stata, difference

I have been struggling to create a new variable that tells me the difference between two different dates. I am using Stata.
The struggle I am having is that the dates are both in different formats.
One is MM/DD/YYYY and the other is MM/DD/YY.

Example of first 4 rows:

| V00EVDATE | DateofDeath |
| --- | --- |
| 8/7/2005 | 12/06/06 |
| 04/15/2006 | 02/13/19 |
| 6/5/2005 | 14/08/14 |
| 07/19/2004 | 2/18/20 |

### Observations:         9,334
Variables:             2

### Variable      Storage   Display
name         type    format

### V00EVDATE       str10   %10s
DateofDeath     str8    %9s

Code attempted:
.gen Months = DateofDeath-V00EVDATE

Comment: Why is this tagged [r]?

Comment: If they are Stata daiily date variables, just use subtraction. If they are not, use -describe- to tell us what they are. Either way, tell us what code you tried and what happened.

Comment: I have also tried R but it doesn't work. Have put my STATA describe and code in the original post. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Note my edit from STATA to Stata. You need to use -daily()- or -date()- to convert each string variable to a Stata numeric daily date variable. See details at -help datetime-.

Comment: For any programming question. show the code you tried. An error report that is just “didn’t work” is not helpful.

Comment: The function -mofd()- converts daily dates to monthly dates.

Comment: I think the issue that I am having is that Stata doesn't seem to understand the way the dates are written because they're written in different forms

Answer (score 0):

The dates in your first variable can all be interpreted as DMY. But contrary to your question not all the dates in your second variable can be interpreted as MDY, and `daily()` needs a third argument to disambiguate the century.

```
* Example generated by -dataex-. For more info, type help dataex
clear
input str10 v00evdate str8 dateofdeath
"8/7/2005"   "12/06/06"
"04/15/2006" "02/13/19"
"6/5/2005"   "14/08/14"
"07/19/2004" "2/18/20" 
end

gen ddate1 = daily(v00evdate, "MDY")

gen ddate2 = daily(dateofdeath, "DMY", 2025)
replace ddate2 = daily(dateofdeath, "MDY", 2025) if missing(ddate2)

gen mdate1 = mofd(ddate1)

gen mdate2 = mofd(ddate2)

format ddate? %td 
format mdate? %tm 

gen wanted = mdate2 - mdate1 

list ddate1-wanted 

     +--------------------------------------------------+
     |    ddate1      ddate2   mdate1   mdate2   wanted |
     |--------------------------------------------------|
  1. | 07aug2005   12jun2006   2005m8   2006m6       10 |
  2. | 15apr2006   13feb2019   2006m4   2019m2      154 |
  3. | 05jun2005   14aug2014   2005m6   2014m8      110 |
  4. | 19jul2004   18feb2020   2004m7   2020m2      187 |
     +--------------------------------------------------+
```

As mentioned in comments, `help datetime` documents the functions you need here.